# Is there a WPF layout control that can be used to dynamically shift between a row and column layout?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I was originally asked to make a control whose child controls were stacked vertically and would fit into the container in which they were placed completely filling that , but after seeing this design I was asked to make them stack horizontally if the aspect ratio were long and thin. Something like the image below;

[image: Correct layout - all space is filled]

I have tried various different containers in various combinations but never quite get what I am after. The closest I get is using a wrap panel, the problem is that the three different parts of the control dont stretch to fit the parent container. The effect I get is closer to this;

[image: The closest I got]

I got this using something like this.

```
    <WrapPanel>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Textbox/>
        </Grid>

        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Textbox/>
        </Grid>

        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Textbox/>
        </Grid>
    </WrapPanel>
```

As you can see I cannot get the controls to fill the container. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you take a look at UniformGrid (with either one row or one column)?

Comment: No, I'm unfamiliar with it - I'll look now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look of this basic wpf containers:
http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/900/wpf-tutorial-layout-panels-containers-layout-transformation-2

You could use a UniformGrid, and either set the `Columns` or the `Rows` property to `1`:

```
<UniformGrid x:Name="uniformGrid" Columns="1">
    <Border Background="Red" />
    <Border Background="Green" />
    <Border Background="Blue" />
</UniformGrid>

<UniformGrid x:Name="uniformGrid" Rows="1">
    <Border Background="Red" />
    <Border Background="Green" />
    <Border Background="Blue" />
</UniformGrid>
```

To switch the orientation, you would simply reset one of the both properties to `0` and set the other to `1`:

```
if (uniformGrid.Rows == 0)
{
    uniformGrid.Rows = 1;
    uniformGrid.Columns = 0;
}
else
{
    uniformGrid.Rows = 0;
    uniformGrid.Columns = 1;
}
```

Comment: I'm currently trying something similar with a dockpanel (although I agree the uniformGrid looks simpler). The problem is the dynamic swithching. Sometimes I want your first grid and at other times I want the second. The column/row count would need to dynamically change from 1 to 3 and vica-versa as the parent's control aspect ratio switched from a "landscape" view to a "portrate" view. Each control you suggest only works for one of the two scenarios

Comment: You would only set *either* the Rows or the Column property. For switching, set the one to `0`, the other to `1`.